# Get field attributes from Esri JavaScript API query

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to get the geometry in an array from a queryTask using the Esri JavaScript API v4.7. I'm sure I'm missing something but I dont know what.  I want to take geometry from this to then create a new record in another service.

```
require([
"esri/tasks/QueryTask", 
"esri/tasks/support/Query"
], 
function(
QueryTask, 
Query
){
  var LayerUrl = "https://services8.arcgis.com/R1PAHHLiCM5plgJt/arcgis/rest/services/MICC_Planning/FeatureServer/0";
  var queryTask = new QueryTask({
    url: LayerUrl
  });
  var lotp="15MPH7941";
  var q="Lotplan LIKE '"+lotp+"'";
  var query = new Query();
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  query.outFields = ["*"];
  query.where = q;
  queryTask.execute(query).then(function(results){
    console.log(4);  
    window.alert(results.features.geometry);
  });

  // When resolved, returns a count of the features that satisfy the query.
  queryTask.executeForCount(query).then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, the problem is that the QueryTask returns a result object, that contains a FeatureSet (which is an array of features). Then if you would like to get the first feature, you have to use `results.features[0]`

So instead of `window.alert(results.features.geometry);`
you have to get the geometry from every result feature:

```
results.features.forEach(function (feature)
    window.alert(feature.geometry);
});
```

I have created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hunizuh/edit?html,console,output) that you can check if you want.